# Built-in modem works in ubuntu 20.04, but not 21.04

Tags: modem, 21.04

my built-in 3G modem (Huawei / HP 840 laptop)  does not show up in 21.04, but worked in 20.04 yesterday.

Followed some guidelines on modem-manager snaps and similar, but they seem to be disfunct and not documented for 21.04.

Comment: As written, this seems like an attempted bug report to me. If your modem is detected by the 20.04 Installer's "Try Ubuntu" environment, but *not* by the 21.04 Installer's "Try Ubuntu" environment, then please file a bug report. If you had to install anything in 20.04 --or change any settings in 20.04-- to make your modem work in 20.04, then add those details to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I never was able to debug how to report bugs to ubuntu. I guess it is intended for the professionals.

Comment: How to report bugs to Ubuntu can be quite simple: `ubuntu-bug <package-name>`. The hard bit comes after that, since we don't know the details of your investigation.